# Solving $x^{\log_3(x-4)} = 3^5 $ for $x$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to solve (not computationally or approximating) the following equation?

$$x^{\log_3(x-4)} = 3^5 $$

Comment: Have you tried guess and check with small integers?

Comment: The answer is not integral because the only way to get 3^5 by taking an integer to a power is for the base to be 3 and the exponent to be 5.

Comment: Letting $3^y=x$ gives $(3^y-4)^y=3^5$

Answer (score 0):

I do not think it can be solved analytically. However we can simplify the equation by taking natural log of both sides

\begin{eqnarray}\log_3(x-4)\ln x&=&5\ln3\\
\ln(x-4)\ln x&=&5(\ln3)^2
\end{eqnarray}

Graphing reveals $x\approx13.902$

Using the approximation

\begin{equation}
\ln(x-4)\ln(x)\approx (\ln(x-2))^2
\end{equation}

gives

\begin{equation}
\ln(x-2)\approx\sqrt{5}\ln3
\end{equation}

giving $x\approx2+3^\sqrt{5}\approx13.6$

[image: intersection of graphs]